# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type ' ', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

After executing the application I get the **"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ClubStarterKit.Web.ViewData.Forum.NewMessageListViewData', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ClubStarterKit.Web.ViewData.Forum.NewMessageListViewData]'.**

In view I have the codes below

```
    <%if ( User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { %>

        <div class="fullwidth" id="message-add-block">
          <%using (Ajax.AsyncForm(Website.Shared.Views.DisplayTemplates.NewForumMessageList, new AsyncFormOptions(AsyncFormType.TargetUpdate, FormMethod.Post, "newMessages", targetUpdate: "messages", elementBlockId: "message-add-block", postRequestFunction: "afterMessageUpdate")))
          {%>
                <h3>Add New Message Final Test</h3>
                <br />
                <%: Html.Wysiwyg("message") %>
                <br />
               <%-- <input type="hidden" value="<%: Model.ThreadSlug %>" name="thread" />--%>
                <input type="hidden" value="-1" name="messageId" />
                <input type="submit" value="Add Message4 final" />
          <%}%>




          <br />
          <a id="newmessage" href="#">New message4 final</a>
        </div>

          <%}%>
```

in the controller the code is

```
 public virtual ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData.Title("New Message");
        return View(Views.List, new ClubStarterKit.Web.Infrastructure.Forum.NewMessageListAction().Execute());
    }
```

and in screenshot below it is :

[image: Error]

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Myapplication.Web.ViewData.application.NewMessageListViewData', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Please advise which area of code is the issue

Comment: What is the return type of `NewMessageListAction().Execute()`?

Comment: The error occurs because you are trying to pass a single object to the view that expects a collection.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the View a single NewMessageListViewData, but it has been strongly typed to accept only objects implementing `IEnumerable<T>` where T is NewMessageListViewData. For example, a `List<NewMessageListViewData>` would work.

As mentioned in the comments, I would start by looking at the return type of ClubStarterKit.Web.Infrastructure.Forum.NewMessageListAction.Execute(), or, if you only intend to display a single instance of NewMessageListViewData in this View, you need to set the model in the View to reflect that.